# Cannot able to push elements into the array

Tags: reactjs

```
state = { driverid: '', history: [{}] }

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

componentDidMount(){

  this.setState({ driverid: this.props.navigation.getParam('driverid', 'NO-ID') }, 
   () => {
    const GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("Booking");
    const query = new Parse.Query(GameScore);
    query.equalTo("driverid", this.state.driverid);
    query.find().then(function (results) {
      console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");

      for (var i = 0; i <= results.length; i++) {
        this.state.history.push(results.get(results[i]))
      }
      console.log(this.state.history)
    });
  });
}
```

I'm not able to `push` elements into the array when executed, the above program gives the following error

> WARN  Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError:
>   undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.history.push')

Answer (score 1):

I can see two thing which could cause your problem. First, do not mutate state like this: `this.state.history.push(results.get(results[i]))` you should always change state using `this.setState` to avoid bugs in the code.

Second try to write callback in then as an arrow function. Using normal function probably changed value of `this` so `this.state` may be something different now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you have not handled the promise rejection. Changing the state will handle with this.setState() is the best practice and the state should be writing like this. This would be a help for you I think

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { driverid: '', history: [{}] }
}


query.find().then((results) => {
  console.log("Successfully retrieved " + results.length + " scores.");

  for (var i = 0; i <= results.length; i++) {
    this.setState({history:this.history.push(results.get(results[i]))})
  }
  console.log(this.state.history)
}).catch((error)=>console.log(error);
```